# java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key when executing KeyManagerFactory.init()

Tags: java, keystore

I have the following code that tries to initialize KeyManagerFactory using SHA-256 hash as password.

```
public static KeyManager[] getKeystoreManagers()
    throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchProviderException {
    KeyStore keystore = getKeyStore();

    if (keystore == null) {
        return null;
    }

    KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());        
    kmf.init(keystore, getMachinePassword(SHA_256).toCharArray());

    return kmf.getKeyManagers();
}
```

getKeyStore() returns my application keystore. getMachinePassword() returns a password using SHA-256, 64 digits password length.
 The problem is that I get the exception when init() is called:

```
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

If I am passing smaller password length lets say, 50 digits the init succeeded. 
 What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: I realized that it is not a password length issue. I've increased the password size to 70 (added some digits to the end of the password) and the init succeeded. So it is something to do with the password itself. I forgot to mention that the keystore password uses the same getMachinePassword(SHA-256), so it is the same password for init.

Comment: hmmm, difficult issue!
What hexadecimal representation are you using to represent the 256 bits -char(64) or varchar(64)?

Comment: I'm using toCharArray() which returns char[] but that is not the issue. Basically, what I'm trying to do is to replace the keystore password that's all. The password is SHA-1 hashed and I want to convert the same password to SHA-256 hashed password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem. The keystore was created using setEntry with specific alias.
 Therefore, in my conversion function I had to get the entry using the old password and set the same entry with the same alias again with the new password. Now, with this updated keystore the `KeyManagerFactory.init()` runs successfully. See the following code below:

```
static void convertPasswordAlgorithm(String keystorePath, String fromAlgorithm, String toAlgorithm) throws Exceptionc {
    FileInputStream fileInStream = null;
    String keystoreFullPath = keystorePath + ISiteConstants.c_FILE_SEPERATOR + KEYSTORE_FILE_NAME;
    KeyStore keyStore;

    try {
        String alias = getCertificateAlias();
        keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        fileInStream = new FileInputStream(keystoreFullPath);

        // Try to load the keystore with fromAlgorithm password hash.
        char[] machineOldAlgPassword = getMachinePassword(fromAlgorithm).toCharArray();
        keyStore.load(fileInStream, machineOldAlgPassword);

        // Save the entry to update
        KeyStore.Entry entry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(machineOldAlgPassword));
        HandleFiles.close(fileInStream);

        // If succeeded, recalculate password using toAlgorithm hash and save.
        String machineNewAlgPassword = getMachinePassword(toAlgorithm);
        keyStore.setEntry(alias, entry, new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(machineNewAlgPassword.toCharArray()));

        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(keystoreFullPath);
        keyStore.store(fileOutputStream, machineNewAlgPassword.toCharArray());
        HandleFiles.close(fileOutputStream);
    } finally {
        HandleFiles.close(fileInStream);
    }
}
```